# Weblogic Deployment issue due to NameAlreadyBoundException - after upgraded weblogic from 10.3.6 to Weblogic 12cR2

Tags: weblogic

My application currently working under weblogic 10.3 with Java 1.6.
Now we are trying to deploy same application to weblogic 12cR2 & java 1.8, below is the error we are facing.

```
Unable to bind Business Interface to the JNDI name: Gen4CServlet_warcontact_Home, throw exception javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [EJB:011224]Unable to bind the interface com.hh.cc.ce.RemoteContactSession to RemoteContactession. Another EJB has already bound an interface to that name.; remaining name 'ejb/Contact#com/ce'. NestedException Message is :[EJB:011224]Unable to bind the interface com.hh.cc.ce.RemoteContactSession to RemoteContactSession. Another EJB has already bound an interface to that name."
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Unable to bind Business Interface to the JNDI name: iLinqGen4CGEServlet_warcontactge_Home, throw exception javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [EJB:011224]Unable to bind the interface com.hh.cc.ce.RemoteContactGESession to RemoteContactGESession. Another EJB has already bound an interface to that name.; remaining name 'ejb/Contact#com/hh/cc/ce'. NestedException Message is :[EJB:011224]Unable to bind the interface com.hh.cc.ce.RemoteContactSession to RemoteContactSession. Another EJB has already bound an interface to that name.
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:123)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:212)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:207)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle KM **Unable To Bind Business Interface To The JNDI Name javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [EJB:011224]Unable to bind (Doc ID 2254400.1),** this can be due to Class-Path entry in MANIFESF.MF file. Try to remove the same redeploy the application.